# finding middle position in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I have tried to follow learning on codeasy.net, I have reached chapter 4 where it asks this:

Write a program that reads from the console three numbers each from the new line and then outputs the middle by the value of these three numbers.

```
Example:
 >54
 >4456
 >2
 54
```

I have tried all the code I know as a beginner and it is still wrong. My current code is this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleInput
{
public class TheMiddle
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

       if (a < b && c < b)
       Console.WriteLine(a);
       if (a < b && b < c)
       Console.WriteLine(b);
       if (c < b && a < c)
       Console.WriteLine(c);
       if (a < b && c > b )
       Console.WriteLine(a);
       else
       if (a > b && c > a)
       Console.WriteLine(a);
       if (a > b && b > c)
       Console.WriteLine(b);
      if (c > b && b > a)
      Console.WriteLine(a);
       if (b > a && c > a)
       Console.WriteLine(c);

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: var middleValue = new []{a,b,c}.OrderBy(x=> x).ElementAt(1);

Comment: Why does your example have 4 numbers instead of 3?

Comment: the example is 3 numbers the result is the forth, I copied just as it is on the website

Comment: thank you Rufus L but it is not correct

Comment: @eocron you are right, but he just started to learn c#, in my opinion i dont think its the right time to use linq.

Comment: @jonathana sorry, can't resist =P Im from generation of malicious one-line code makers =D

Answer (score 3):

You need to make more comparisons.  There are 3 cases.

```
if((a <= b && b <= c) || (c <= b && b <= a))
    Console.WriteLine(b);
if((b <= a && a <= c) || (c <= a && a <= b))
    Console.WriteLine(a);
if((a <= c && c <= b) || (b <= c && c <= a))
    Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Basically the number is in the middle of the other two and you have to check the case where the the other two numbers are on either side.  So for example `b` is in the middle if it's between `a` and `c` in that order, or between `c` and `a` in that order.

Comment: I have tried this and it says that I need to find the middle position of the numbers, so if i have 45, 67, 89 the middle position i need to find. Thanks for the help i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleInput
{
public class TheMiddle
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int result;
        if (a < b)
        {
            if (c < a)
                result = a;
            else if (c > b)
                result = b;
            else
                result = c;
        }
        else
        {
            if (c < b)
                result = b;
            else if (c > a)
                result = a;
            else
                result = c;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
  }
}
```

this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by sorting your values and taking middle:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);
list.Add(c);
list.Sort();
var middleValue = list[list.Count/2];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the site teaches me everything I need up to the point of answering the questions, they did not teach me that yet so it is incorrect when i enter it.